# jQuery: grabbing form values

Tags: jquery

If form is submitted to a function using onsubmit(), how can I get an array of the values of all checkboxes with name='values[]' ?

EDIT: originally I mentioned radio buttons, this is wrong - checkboxes is correct.

EDIT: line below only gets the value of the first one, obviously

```
$("input[name='values[]']:checked").val()
```

Also, how can I get the number of checkboxes that were checked when the form was submitted?

Comment: if `input[name=values[]]` is a radio button, there's only going to be one `:checked` value due to the nature of radio buttons...you have to remove that to get all values

Comment: yeah sorry, I meant checkboxes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`val` returns a single value. To get all values, use `map`:

```
var selectedValues = $("input[name^='values']:checked").map(
       function(){ return $(this).val(); }).get();
```

This returns an array with all selected values. To get a dash-delimited string:

```
var dashed = selectedValues.join('-');
```

Comment: This returns nothing, just blank value

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `:checked`, and too many single quotes. Here's a working example: http://jsbin.com/abovi

Comment: Perfect! Is there any way to replace the comma with a dash?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('#formId').serializeArray();
```

Comment: A nice idea, but lacks filtering to radio buttons and checkboxes.